# Laravel 4 - does not throw that variable is undefined in one of the views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Made testing controller:

```
class Home1Controller extends BaseController {


public function __construct() {

    ini_set('show_errors', true);
}

public function getTest() {

    $data['subview'] = $this->aaa();

    return View::make('test.bbb', $data);

}

private function aaa() {

    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $data['subviews'][] = $this->ccc();
    }

    return View::make('test.aaa', $data);
}

private function ccc() {

    return View::make('test.ccc');
}
```

}

And the views:

aaa.blade.php:

```
<div>

aaa

<p>throws that $a is undefined </p>

{{-- $a --}}

@foreach ($subviews as $subview)

    {{ $subview }}

@endforeach
```

bbb.blade.php

```
<style type="text/css">
 div    {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 1px;
margin: 1px;
}
</style>

<div>
<p>bbb</p>
<p>throws that $a is undefined</p>
{{ $subview }}



{{-- $a --}}


</div>
```

ccc.blade.php:

```
<div> 
 ccc

 does not throw that $a is undefined

{{-- $a --}}
</div>
```

Now when I uncomment variable $a in aaa or bbb views, there is standard laravel error displayed.

But when I uncomment in ccc view - error is not displayed. It is rendered this instead:

```
aaa
throws that $a is undefined
```

I was testing same technique at my other computer, and I got error displaying at all views as I expect. So why could I dont get on this computer? Where should I look at?

**Edited**

If I add to constructor

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

then one error is shown:

Fatal error: Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception in /home/darius/repos/dashboard/app/storage/views/3b6a644a21beb63c65a709b559771162 on line 11

and in that view line 11 was in aaa view:

```
    <?php echo $subview; ?>
```

Btw I was testing on another - linux server now, its same.

Comment: maybe different error reporting levels in php.ini

Comment: ok, if I set in the constructor error_reporting(-1); then it should get all errors not matter what I guess. But on the other hand - usually errors use laravel's styling, and this setting deals with php. So it feels somehow that somewhere in the laravel installation something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that if I call

```
return View::make('test.ccc')->render();
```

then it throws that variable is undefined.

By this post I found.

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10378

Now I just dont get why its hidden so deeply in documentation?

For example here:

http://laravel.com/docs/responses

it is every where showing that view::make is enough.

Here it also is not talked about:

http://laravel.com/docs/templates

Only in there the method is written:

http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.View.View.html